# Motherboard fried on Windows RAID 1 System, do I have to reformat?

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, raid1

A faulty power supply fried my motherboard and I need some help. I had a spare motherboard lying around and hooked it up to one of the hard drives to see if I could just continue chugging along. Unfortunately Windows continues to BSOD with error 0000007b which seems to be concerned about the new hard drive controller.

Am I going to have to reformat or is there a way to get Windows to stop using the RAID array and use the new hard drive controller?

Comment: Can you enter Safe Mode?

Comment: No it halts at acpitabl.dat and restarts the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace a failed motherboard with a new motherboard and to then reconfigure Windows to work with the new motherboard, do the following:

> 1. Turn off the computer.
> 2. Replace the existing motherboard with the new motherboard.
> 3. Insert your Windows Server 2003 CD in the CD-ROM drive or the DVD-ROM drive, and start the computer from the CD.
> 4. When you are prompted **To set up Windows now, press ENTER**, press ENTER.
>
>    Setup looks for any previous installations of Windows Server 2003 on the hard disk and then displays a list of any previous installations that it finds.
>
>    Use the arrow keys to select the installation that you want to repair, and then press R to select the **To repair the selected Windows installation, press R** option.
> 5. This will start the repair of your previous Windows Server 2003 installation.
>
>    Follow the instructions on the screen, and allow Setup to complete the repair of the previous Windows Server 2003 installation.
>
>    Setup installs the HAL, the IDE controller drivers, and any other drivers that the new motherboard must have.
> 6. After the repair is completed, reinstall any service packs or hotfixes that you had previously installed.

Source: [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824125)

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, then your RAID1 array is a simply copied pair, and you can run directly from 1 of the hard disks, without any RAID controller or driver.

Comment: That's what I thought too, however, it seems that since it used to be part of a raid pair there is an extra step of altering hard drive controller drivers that wouldn't otherwise be necessary. A small price to pay versus losing all my data but it is annoying that windows can't just figure this out.

Comment: In a half-lucky situation like that, the 'quick-repair' procedure (as indicated by the George's) is the most efficient way. Hint: I'd give them the 'correct solution' tick :-)